# Apply the same conditional formatting custom rule to multiple ranges on the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have created a weekly tracker on Google Sheets, with the days organized in columns K through AI. Each day has three columns dedicated to tasks, assigned personnel, and notes. I have successfully applied a conditional formatting rule to the range L6:O36, which colors the rows based on the assigned person.

However, when I attempt to apply the same rule to the range P6:S36, it does not work. I'm puzzled as to why this is happening. Could you please help me understand the reason behind this issue?

Here is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet:  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eoDD7ODEnBvUCANEaGuJcwCY93DTjuMiDvmQ71G0QY4/edit#gid=1816207673

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The question lacks details. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171270/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: For some clues, see [this explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60050658?msgid=60238341) of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] and review [ask].  This question has helpful comments that have not yet been addressed. I recommend you review the comments and [edit] your question accordingly.  Do not create duplicate questions.  The [duplicate created yesterday](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171333) has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing conditional formatting rules are hard-coded to refer to column `L6:L36` and will therefore not work in the columns to the right or the rows to the bottom.

To make it work, apply your [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rules to the open-ended range `L6:AI` and modify the rules like this:

```
="Sarah" = offset(L6, 0, -mod(column() - column($L$1), 4))
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eoDD7ODEnBvUCANEaGuJcwCY93DTjuMiDvmQ71G0QY4/edit#gid=1023759488).

Comment: @doubleunary- thank you!
Is it possible to add another custom rule that will return the range back to white with a strike through applied if the status is marked as "Complete"?

Comment: Yes. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.